# gnu-radio installation error

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, gnuradio

I get the following error on installing gnuradio. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

```
GRAS Module loader fail: /usr/lib/gras/modules/grex/libgrex_uhd.so
>>> GRAS: The debug asserts are enabled. <<<
Could not import /usr/lib/gras/python/grex/UHDTypes.py libuhd.so.003: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/gras/GRAS_Loader.py", line 14, in __try_module_import
module = imp.load_module(module_name, fp, pathname, description)
File "/usr/lib/gras/python/grex/UHDTypes.py", line 26, in <module>
_UHDTypes = swig_import_helper()
File "/usr/lib/gras/python/grex/UHDTypes.py", line 22, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_UHDTypes', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: libuhd.so.003: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Could not import /usr/lib/gras/python/grex/_UHDTypes.so libuhd.so.003: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/gras/GRAS_Loader.py", line 14, in __try_module_import
module = imp.load_module(module_name, fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: libuhd.so.003: cannot open shared object
```

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a case of library versions missing or version mismatch; if you updated UHD after building GRAS/GNU Radio, you will end up with this. 
The only solution is to build GNU Radio using the same version of the UHD library that you will use at run time.

Building GNU Radio from source can be done rather easy with pyBOMBS on Ubuntu. This might be a really good time to update your three-years old version of Ubuntu; with 14.04LTS being here, there's hardly reason to continue using an outdated version of your distro, unless your bound by very specific Software (which might run really fine within a virtual machine!).

Other than that, there's not been development on GRAS in over a year -- the author has a new project, pothos, and some of the concepts behind GRAS went into regular GNU Radio. So unless you really know what you're doing, go for the latest vanilla GNU Radio instead of GRAS.